# error Cannot load M3U8:Unable to parse URL in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am working with the jwplayer for HLS streaming,but i am getting error like

```
Cannot load M3U8:Unable to parse URL
```

Can anyone please tell me why i am getting issue like this, 
Here is my code HLS streaming

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/DkwOvSfA.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">Loading the player...</div>

<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://localhost:8080/jwplayer/testing.m3u8",
    image: "https://testvideoout.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Thumb/Thumb_Videos_29_1446555606635_00001.png",
});    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

testing.m3u8 :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1643600,RESOLUTION=1280x720
hls1080m_Videos_36_1200_1459579486311
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1093600,RESOLUTION=854x480
hls720m_Videos_36_1200_1459579486311
```

This both files are in my jwplayer folder
hls1080m_Videos_36_1200_1459579486311,hls720m_Videos_36_1200_1459579486311

m3u8 file is working with the VLC player, it means my m3u8 file is perfect

What is issue with it ? How can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If these are child manifests, you'll need to be sure to include the .m3u8 extension onto them, and ensure that they're referenced with those extensions as well. Otherwise the player will not be able to recognize and parse them correctly.

Otherwise, if you're still having issues, please include a public-facing link so that we can take a look and assist.